# Yum install dependencies on RHEL

Tags: updates, redhat-enterprise-linux, openssl, yum, rpm

Trying to install openssl-devel for keepalived-1.4.5 on RHEL7.4.

after sudo yum install openssl-devel I'm getting

```
...<Processing Dependencies>
Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package krb5-workstation-1.15.1-8.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.4)
Requires: libkadm5(x86-64) = 1.15.1-8.el7
Removing: libkadm5-1.15.1-8.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.4)
    libkadm5(x86-64) = 1.15.1-8.el7
Updated by: libkadm5-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64
    libkadm(x86-64) = 1.15.1-19.el7
.....<More Dependency Errors>
```

Other dependency errors show available packages in the repos accessible to me. Wondering how to remedy this considering I can't get access to updated repos due to satellite servers though I can get rpm's from a vendor. Most dependencies were already resolved by creating a local repo for yum using the packages the vendor could find with their up to date repo.

Do I need to be updating krb5-workstation? If this is done would it effect kerberos configuration?

Struggling to make sense of the error message so an explanation of how to continue troubleshooting would be phenomenal.

Answer (score 0):

libkadm5 and krb5-workstation are subpackages of krb5 package. And both need to be at the same version-release.

You have in repo newer libkadm5 (1.15.1-19.el7) but not krb5-workstation of the same version.